# calculating angle based on user touch

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a game with a character that can cast fire balls. Right now in my game, when I tap anywhere on the screen, I shoot a fireball at my touch point. For this fireball I'm using an SKEmitterNode where I've created a fireball particle emitter.

The problem I'm running into is, my fireball has an angle set already, but I want that angle to change based on where I tap, so that the trailing flames are behind the fireball, not going up or down or whatever I've set it to in the sks file.

I've never done something like this, is there something built into swift already for calculating angles? I can't find much on google

Comment: I might not get the whole idea, but: you have the origin of the fireball, and the destination point, right? If so, calculating the angle is a simple trigonometric operation.

Comment: you're right, let me find the equation!

Comment: If my math doesn't fail me, it should be arctan

Comment: you're right, I think its angleInDegrees = arctan(deltaY / deltaX) * 180 / PI

Comment: The two argument form `atan2(deltaY,deltaX)` would be better. If you do the division first, you lose information about which quadrant you're in.

Comment: @JimLewis does atan2 return degrees or radians? right now my fireball is shooting with the right angle, but the trailing flames are in front of the fireball rather than behind it, can't figure out how to fix this

Comment: @Abdul, I'm pretty sure the result is in radians.  And if `atan2(deltaY,deltaX)` gives the direction of motion, `atan2(-deltaY, -deltaX)` should give the direction of the flames.

Comment: `atan2()` returns an angle in radians. You can also change the flame's direction by adding M_PI to `atan2(deltaY,deltaX)` to avoid the extra `atan2()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1) first one is that you can use :

```
fireBall.moveTo(touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y)
```

function so you can avoid use angles (if I understand you correctly). touchLocation is CGPoint of location of the touch event.

2) second one use as it was said before you will get an angle:

```
atan2(deltaY,deltaX)
```